# Fixing right alignment of string formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I'm trying to align the output of the list like shown:

[image]

But it keeps coming out like this:

[image]

My code for all of this is:

```
subject_amount = int(input("\nHow many subject do you want to enrol? "))

class Subject:
def __init__(self, subject_code, credit_point):
    self.subject_code = subject_code
    self.credit_point = credit_point

subjects = []

for i in range(1, (subject_amount + 1)):
subject_code = input("\nEnter subject " + str(i) + ": ")
credit_point = int(input("Enter subject " + str(i) + " credit point: "))
subject = Subject(subject_code, credit_point)
subjects.append(subject)

print ("\nSelected subjects: ")

i, total = 0, 0

print("{0:<} {1:>11}".format("Subject: ", "CP"))

while(i < subject_amount):
print("{0:<} {1:14}".format(subjects[i].subject_code, subjects[i].credit_point))
total += subjects[i].credit_point
i = i + 1

print("{0:<} {1:>11}".format("Total cp: ", total))
```

I've tried changing the values for the spacing as well with no results.

Any feedback on the rest of my code is also greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this using plain Python formatting because the amount of padding depends on both strings. Try defining a function such as:

```
def format_justified(left, right, total):
    padding = total - len(left)
    return "{{0}}{{1:>{}}}".format(padding).format(left, right)
```

then simply use:

```
print(format_justified("Total cp:", total, 25))
```

where 25 is the total line width you want.